# Изменения параметров страницы в RTF файле (программно)

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, печать

Всем привет! Интересует следующий вопрос: Делаю чек в RTF файле (логотип, текст, штрих-код). Ширина бумаги - 80 мм. Скажите, если возможность програмно сохранить файл с параметрами страницы, которые мне нужны (отступы, ширина страницы, длинна и т.д.), а не стандартными? (Использую RichTextBox для формирования файла).